# pyproject.toml dynamic version dependency

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I have a Python package (aabbcc) in namespace form consisting of two sub-packages (aabbcc-core, aabbcc-aws) that I am converting over to pyproject.toml format for packaging. I would like them to be versioned together and I got that to work using dynamic version reference pointing to a text file VERSION - below is my pyproject.toml for the aabbcc-aws subpackage:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=64.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "aabbcc-aws"
dynamic = ["version"]
dependencies = ["boto3","aabbcc-core"]
requires-python = ">=3.12"

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {file = "../VERSION"}
```

What I would like to be able to do is for aabbcc-aws dependencies to point to aabbcc-core package of the same version. Essentially I want to figure out making dependencies dynamic and have the resulting dependency for aabbcc-aws be:

```
[project]
dependencies = ["boto3","aabbcc-core==VERSION"]
```

And similarly to have the main package be:

```
[project]
dependencies = ["aabbcc-core==VERSION"]

[project.optional-dependencies]
aws = ["aabbcc-aws==VERSION"]
```

Is there any way to plug in this VERSION string dynamically into dependencies and optional-dependencies sections?

Answer (score 1):

As per `setuptools==69.1.1` and the [latest `pyproject.toml` spec](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/pyproject-toml/), this is not "natively" supported.

Note however that you can "complement" `pyproject.toml` with `setup.py` as long as you set `project.dynamic` is set accordingly. This allows you to write arbitrary customisation in Python.

You can try something like the following (untested, may require adjustments):

```ini
# pyproject.toml

...

[project]
name = "aabbcc-aws"
dynamic = ["version", "dependencies", "optional-dependencies"]
requires-python = ">=3.12"

...
```

```py
# setup.py

...

from pathlib import Path

VERSION = Path('VERSION').read_text(encoding="utf-8")
# Note that if you use `..` you are probably breaking the builds from `sdist`.
# The build needs to be self-contained using only files that are present in the `sdist`.

dependencies_text = Path("dependencies.in").read_text(encoding="utf-8")
dependencies = dependencies_text.replace("VERSION", VERSION).splitlines()
# ... something similar for optional_dependencies ...

setup(
  ...
  install_requires=dependencies,
  extras_require=optional_dependencies,
  ...
)
```

Notes about this approach:

- `setup.py` itself is not deprecated. What is deprecated is using it as a CLI tool.
- It is completely fine to keep the static bits in `pyproject.toml` and writing customisations in `setup.py`.

Evidence: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#setuppy-discouraged

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try this out. Do you know if adding the setup.py in this manner will cause any issues with editable installs? I see this Note on the setuptools user guide mentioning that "Newer versions of pip no longer run the fallback command python setup.py develop when the pyproject.toml file is present." https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html#legacy-behavior
I think this was the reason by which I was trying to avoid including it and rely on the newer pyproject.toml only

Comment: The best is to try it out and see how it goes.

For editable installs,  the new behviour is for `pip` to call a set of APIs in `setuptools.build_meta`, instead of simply running `python setup.py develop`.

But that is fine in principle because `setuptools.build_meta` still parses `setup.py`.
If `setup.py` is written with that approach in mind (i.e. to be a provider of metadata and build config) instead of being the primary entry-point of the build process, things should work out fine.